# How to fill a rectangle with two corners on the function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to be able to apply the same thing in the following figure for any function:

[image]

Right now my code is like this(which is an edited version of some post here in Tex.sx):
Wich only fills under the curve completely!

```
\documentclass[11pt,bezier]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=9,xlabel={Y},ymin=0,ymax=10] 
        \addplot[color=black,domain=-1:9,samples=100]
            {(-(x-3)^2+(x-3)^4-(x-1)^3+4)/40+5};
        \addplot[color=black,fill=lime,  domain=5.8:7,samples=100]
            {(-(x-3)^2+(x-3)^4-(x-1)^3+4)/40+5} \closedcycle;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer to have boundaries around the rectangle. Thanks again.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill, I did but I don't know what I have to do to be able to make it run!

Comment: You need to add `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and eliminate the `$` signs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use relative coordinates and `--cycle` (instead of `\closedcycle`) to get:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=9,xlabel={Y},ymin=0,ymax=10] 
        \addplot[color=black,domain=-1:9,samples=100] {(-(x-3)^2+(x-3)^4-(x-1)^3+4)/40+5};
        \addplot[color=black,fill=lime,  domain=5.8:7,samples=100] 
            {(-(x-3)^2+(x-3)^4-(x-1)^3+4)/40+5} -- +(axis direction cs:-1.2,0)--cycle;
        \addplot[color=black,fill=cyan,  domain=7:5.8,samples=100] 
            {(-(x-3)^2+(x-3)^4-(x-1)^3+4)/40+5} -- +(axis direction cs:1.2,0)--cycle;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)